# By using Gstreamer - how to receive a live-source stream by rtsp-server and send it to other client?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, vlc, rtsp, rtsp-client

I'm trying to build a quite simple RTSP-server (apparently, it's less simple then I thought) with [gst-rtsp-server](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server).

I used the `'test-record'` example to RECORD by the rtsp-server a stream from a rtsp-client (FFmpeg in my case). It seems to work, I can see a valid sequence in wireshark.

Later I used the `'test-launch'` example to PLAY a test stream, so I can read it with rtsp-client (FFplay) and it also works well.

However, I don't understand how to combine the two examples into one rtsp-server that can RECORD a stream (a live-source) from one rtsp-client, and then send (PLAY) this stream to a second (third or even fourth) rtsp-client.

Any idea if the Gstreamer infrastructure supports this functionality ? And if so, any tips how to do it ?

Comment: I did implement such behavior: https://github.com/RSATom/RtspRestreamServer

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help!!! However I'm getting failure when trying to compile it: ../RestreamServerLib/libRestreamServerLib.a(Server.cpp.o): In function `RestreamServerLib::Server::initStaticServer()': Server.cpp:(.text+0x2800): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_transport_mode' - perhaps I'm installing the wrong version of one of the packages before the compilation ?

Comment: It looks like code is outdated a little bit... fixing...

Comment: I've found and fixed some build issue, but unfortunately it's not related to your problem. Can you please create new issue on GitHub to move your problem discussion there?

Comment: Hi, I've opened a new issue as your request. Logs are also attach. Again, your help is mush appreciated.